SvelteKit: "No overload matches this call" error invite.config.js when working with vitest
I just created an app with pnpx sv create sveltekit-test2
and checked vitest
and now when I run pnpm check I get this error:
Loading svelte-check in workspace: /home/sas/devel/apps/dgiit/proyectos/tmp/sveltekit-test
Getting Svelte diagnostics...

/home/sas/devel/apps/dgiit/proyectos/tmp/sveltekit-test/vite.config.ts:5:12
Error: No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.

this is my vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from "vitest/config";
import { sveltekit } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [sveltekit()],

    test: {
        include: ['src/**/*.{test,spec}.{js,ts}']
    }
});

and here's the same error on vscode

the defineConfig from the vite package works ok, btw


This is probably a compatiblity issue between Vitest and Vite 6. See this comment:

As @dummdidumm mentioned, this is an issue of having multiple Vite versions. vitest just recently reverted their Vite 6 support in their v2.1.7 release, causing Vite 5 & 6 to be installed and the types to be mismatched

Reverting Vite to v5 might work, I have also seen somewhere that the Vitest v3 beta also fixes this.
This should just be a type error, so you could probably ignore it using an instruction like // @ts-expect-error.

thanks a lot, that's the correct anser. What would be the "best" way to handle this?
Add the ts-expect-error and wait for some upgrade to fix it? eventually vitest will switch back to vite 6 I guess

That is what I would do unless there are run-time issues.
